If $X$ is a strong deformation retract of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then is $X$ simply connected at infinity?
Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and assume there is a strong deformation retract from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $X$.  Is $X$ necessarily simply connected at infinity?
(Edit) Follow up question: if there is a proper strong deformation retract from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $X$, then is $X$ simply connected at infinity?
My thoughts/comments:

$X$ is of course contractible.  I suppose (though perhaps I'm wrong) that if we only had a deformation retract from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $X$, then $X$ would not have to be simply connected at infinity (because of the Whitehead manifold).


What about a plane $\mathbb{R}^2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$?

Every contractible ENR is a strong deformation retract of some euclidean space (this includes the Whitehead manifold).

No, consider the point. You'd have to consider proper strong deformation retracts.

Thanks for the comments!  A couple questions:
(1) How is $\mathbb{R}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ an example?  I thought $\mathbb{R}^2$ is simply connected at infinity.
(2) @FernandoMuro Are you saying that if $X$ is a proper strong deformation retract of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $X$ must be simply connected at infinity?  (I edited the question to ask about properness too.)

The plane is not simply connected at infinity...

Proper homotopy equivalence preserves homotopy groups at infinity.

@NajibIdrissi Ok, I think I see your point: The plane is not simply connected at infinity (but the projective plane would be).  On the other hand, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is simply connected at infinity for all $n \geq 3$, correct?  Thanks, this is clarifying things for me.

@ccriscitiello the projective plane is not simply connected at infinity either. It's compact. Also, your follow-up question is already answered in my comment.

You don't need to consider proper strong deformation retracts. It is enough that $X$ is a proper retract of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n\geq3$.
